# Import opencv-python single modules

Tags: python-import, pyinstaller, opencv, python

I'm trying to create a python app that uses opencv as backend, the problem arise when i try to export the application using `pyinstaller`, in fact, even though i use very few functions of cv2:

```
from cv2 import normalize, cvtColor, applyColorMap, imread, NORM_MINMAX, COLORMAP_JET, COLOR_BGR2RGB
```

everytime i 'pyinstall' the script the resulting folder is massive (>100mb). This is because `pyinstaller` imports the whole opencv library:

```
libopencv_aruco.so.3.3        libopencv_dnn.so.3.3         libopencv_hdf.so.3.3        libopencv_objdetect.so.3.3         libopencv_rgbd.so.3.3              libopencv_text.so.3.3         libopencv_xphoto.so.3.3
libopencv_bgsegm.so.3.3       libopencv_face.so.3.3        libopencv_highgui.so.3.3    libopencv_optflow.so.3.3           libopencv_saliency.so.3.3          libopencv_tracking.so.3.3     cv2.so
libopencv_bioinspired.so.3.3  libopencv_features2d.so.3.3  libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3  libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so.3.3  libopencv_shape.so.3.3             libopencv_videoio.so.3.3
libopencv_calib3d.so.3.3      libopencv_flann.so.3.3       libopencv_img_hash.so.3.3   libopencv_photo.so.3.3             libopencv_stitching.so.3.3         libopencv_video.so.3.3
libopencv_ccalib.so.3.3       libopencv_freetype.so.3.3    libopencv_imgproc.so.3.3    libopencv_plot.so.3.3              libopencv_structured_light.so.3.3  libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.3.3
libopencv_core.so.3.3         libopencv_fuzzy.so.3.3       libopencv_ml.so.3.3         libopencv_reg.so.3.3               libopencv_surface_matching.so.3.3  libopencv_ximgproc.so.3.3
```

I'm using very few components of cv2, is it possible to import just the required ones? I already tried to import manually the shared libraries but of course it doesn't work because they do not have the **init** function:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init__main__)
```

Any solution that will decrease the size of my deliverable will be appreciated.

Comment: What other libraries are you using? I was compiling `tensorflow` and `opencv` using `pyinstaller` and executable was around 80MB

Comment: what opencv version are you using?

Comment: I use ver 3.3.0..

Comment: and what is the size of your libopencv*.so files?